# iOS Swift 1.2 - Primitive Type Comparison Failure

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, primitive-types

I have a function that gets and parses data from Firebase.  I have a validation "parseUserModel) that returns "Bool" type if the model meets the requirements to pass.  I set this value to validUser which is of Bool type.  The model I'm pulling actually passes and returns a boolean of true.

Here's where the issue happens.

`If(validUser) { ... code ... } fails even though the validUser is "true".`

I've played around with the actual return type and I've tried these things:

1. validUser.boolValue and setting this inside the if(validUser.boolValue)

   - this fails
2. setting the if(validUser) { ... code ... }

   - this fails
3. setting the if(validUser == true) {..code..}

   - this fails
4. setting the if(validUser.boolValue == true) {code}

   - this fails

I'm all out of ideas as to why exactly this is failing.  I'm comparing a primitive type (I'm assuming) to another primitive type.

**My Questions**

1. is the 'true' keyword in Swift not actually a Bool object type?
2. why is this failing when I'm explicitly asking for the boolValue?
3. is their a Swift bug I should know about?
4. is the if statement not doing what I think it should be doing?

**Retrieve Data Function**

```
public static func retrieveUserData(user:UserModel, completion:(success:Bool)->Void){
    if(user.username != nil){
        let fbRef = Firebase(url: GlobalVariables().FB_BASE_URL+"users/\(user.username)")
        fbRef.observeSingleEventOfType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            if(snapshot.value != nil){
                let validUser:Bool = UserModel.sharedInstance.parseUserData(JSON(snapshot.value))
                println(validUser)
                println(validUser.boolValue)
                if(validUser.boolValue){
                    completion(success: true)
                } else {
                    completion(success: false)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Parse Model and Validate**

```
public func parseUserData(data:JSON) -> Bool {
    var uName:String!
    var uFullName:String!

    if let username = data["username"].string {
        UserModel.sharedInstance.username = username
    }

    if let fullName = data["fullName"].string {
        UserModel.sharedInstance.fullName = fullName
    } else {
        return false
    }

    if let biography = data["biography"].string {
        UserModel.sharedInstance.biography = biography
    }

    if let email = data["email"].string {
        UserModel.sharedInstance.email = email
    }

    if let plistID = data["playlistCollectionID"].string {
        UserModel.sharedInstance.playlistCollectionID = plistID
    } else {
        //generate a playlistCollectionID because the user doesn't have one
        UserModel.sharedInstance.playlistCollectionID = NSUUID().UUIDString
    }
    if(UserModel.validateUserObject(UserModel.sharedInstance)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

**Println() log from Xcode**
true 
true

the above two true are coming from the retrieval code
println(validUser) and println(validUser.boolValue)

Comment: Are you saying that it's executing `completion(success: false)` instead of `completion(success: true)`? Can you confirm with a breakpoint that you're actually hitting that line?

Answer (score 2):

The Bool type in Swift conforms to [BooleanType](http://swiftdoc.org/protocol/BooleanType/), which has the member:

`var boolValue: Bool { get }`

The value stored in validUser is definitely a Bool, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to put it in a variable of the Bool type.

The most likely situation here is that there is a bug in your code. Go over it again and make sure that it's actually entering the else block instead of the if block.

As a side note, the Swift formatting convention for if statements looks like this:

```
if condition {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

as opposed to `if(condition){...`

Comment: After tracing the code, I noticed the function specialization was "exploding".  #0 0x0000000109da5812 in function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded> of Geekin_Radio.UserModel.parseUserData (Geekin_Radio.UserModel)(Geekin_Radio.JSON) -> Swift.Bool at /Users/timothybarrett/Documents/QA/Geekin Radio/UserModel.swift:192

However the function was still returning true.  I was under the assumption that an exploded function would trigger a crash however it does not and the function goes on executing successfully even though it crashed.

Comment: This still doesn't really solve the issue as to why a "true" boolean is failing.  The println() statement is printing out true even though the function itself has crashed.  I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to step through the code.  I was stepping through the code and it never crashed so I never thought to look at the thread information.  :)

Also, I come from a C++ background so if [statement] looks very strange to me.  I would rather do if ( statement ) { } but to each their own I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Due to my own idiocy I was sending the shared user instance UserModel into itself.

```
private static func validateUserObject(object:UserModel) -> Bool {
    println(object.username)
    println(object.fullName)
    if(object.username != nil && object.fullName != nil){
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

So I would call the method like this...

`UserModel.sharedInstance.validateUserObject(self)`

This would cause the Function specialization explosion.  This would not crash the app (which is the strange part).  It would continue and return the true boolean (because the model was valid).